# Are the mRNA vaccines from Pfizer and Moderna vegan?

Tags: covid-19, vaccines, vegetarianism

The mRNA vaccines from both Pfizer and Moderna contain cholesterol.

On [the website for the UK National Health System NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/coronavirus-vaccination/coronavirus-vaccine/) we may read:

> The COVID-19 vaccines do not contain egg or animal products.

Another report indicates it contains no animal-derived cholesterol (but curiously notes that cow's milk was used in the manufacturing process):

> Do Vaccines Contain Animal Ingredients?
>
> The Pfizer, Moderna, and Janssen vaccines are free of animal-derived ingredients, in contrast to many other vaccines that include shark squalene, gelatin, cholesterol, egg, and milk. Pfizer has reported that its vaccine used a cow’s milk component in the manufacturing process, but the vaccine does not contain this ingredient.
>
> — Physicians Committee for Responsible Medicine: ["COVID-19 Vaccines: Safety and Efficacy"](https://www.pcrm.org/news/good-science-digest/covid-19-vaccines-safety-and-efficacy), Good Science Digest, Mar 31, 2021

However, Magdeburg University are working on an alternative source of cholesterol. They firmly *deny* that the current crop of vaccines are vegan. They even claim they are potentially unsafe:

> Vaccines based on mRNA […] are still based on animal cholesterol, which has several disadvantages.
>
> For the industrial production of vaccines, the cholesterol is extracted from sheep's wool or animal tissue, for example. Here, however, there is a risk of triggering brain diseases through unintentional transmission - damage to the brain known as prion disease. A very well-known form in cattle since the 1990s is BSE.
>
> A risk that could be eliminated in the future with the help of research from Magdeburg.
>
> — ["Pflanzlich statt tierisch Uni Magdeburg macht RNA-Impfstoffe 'vegan' und sicherer", MDR, 31. May 2021.](https://www.mdr.de/wissen/uni-magdeburg-mrna-impfstoff-pflanzlich-statt-tierisch-100.html) *[Translated from German, LLC]*

Closer to the source:

> Chemists at Otto von Guericke University Magdeburg […] have succeeded for the first time in producing pharmaceutical cholesterol from plant-based raw materials using a highly effective process. In the future this will make it possible to make available large quantities of the molecule urgently needed for the production and administration of modern mRNA-based vaccines, […]
>
> — Universität Magdeburg: ["Gamechanger in der Impfstoffproduktion"](https://www.ovgu.de/lipide-path-2,13,31924,31926.html), Press Release, 25.05.2021. *[Translated from German, LLC]*

The general sources for injectable cholesterol are confirmed by one phospholipide manufacturer:

> Source of cholesterol
> The medicinal cholesterol CHO-HP is in great demand every year. However, because it is a multi-chiral substance and is difficult to synthesize, it is currently obtained by two methods: animal tissue extraction and lanolin extraction. […] However, with the emphasis on drug safety, cholesterol derived from lanolin will surely gradually replace cholesterol derived from animal organs.
>
> — ["Introduction to the source and application of cholesterol"](http://en.avt-avt.com/p-company.html), AVT, 2020-09-30.

All this gets even more complicated when looking at the list of prescribed/allowed ingredients as listed in the European Pharmacopeia (Ph. Eur.):

> Cholesterol For Parenteral Use –  Cholesterolum ad usum parenteralem C27H46O [57-88-5] Mr 386.7
> Definition:
> Cholest-5-en-3β-ol **obtained from Wool fat (0134).** *[emphasis added, LLC]*
>
> — Council of Europe: "European Pharmacopoeia", <sup>10</sup>2019. (p 2202)

Let's focus on [Pfizer/BionTech's Comirnaty/Tozinameran mRNA vaccine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfizer%E2%80%93BioNTech_COVID-19_vaccine):

> Composition
> In addition to the mRNA molecule, the vaccine contains the following inactive ingredients (excipients):
>
> ALC-0315, ((4-hydroxybutyl)azanediyl)bis(hexane-6,1-diyl)bis(2-hexyldecanoate), ALC-0159, 2-[(polyethylene glycol)-2000]-N,N-ditetradecylacetamide,  1,2-distearoyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphocholine (DSPC), **cholesterol** *[emphasis added, LLC]*

Comirnaty's package leaflet doesn't state the source of the cholesterol (which it normally *has* to do as well?).

It is clear that a requirement for prior animal testing poses a problem for strict vegans, for any vaccine.

Now it seems that there is also conflicting information out there for the actual ingredients used in manufacturing, and especially for the contents of the finished product:

- whether 'some animal derived products were used during manufacturing but not contained in final product'
- as well as 'some animal derived products *are* contained in the final product'
- that the 'product is vegan', which would at least require of it to be free of animal derived products in the finished product
- that the final product would by law *be required* to contain animal derived products, specifically cholesterol (As otherwise it would be not marketable at all, animal source being the only approved source, neither plant derived not fully synthetic sources allowed, even if structurally identical.)

Some say the final product is vegan, while some say the exact opposite.

Does Pfizer/BionTech's Comirnaty/Tozinameran mRNA vaccine contain in the final product animal-derived cholesterol, making it [non-vegan](https://logicalharmony.net/animal-ingredients-what-is-lanolin/)?

Comment: Maybe it's the particular molecule they are using in the vaccine, but [cholesterol total synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesterol_total_synthesis) has existed since the 1950s.

Comment: This [FDA explanation](https://www.fda.gov/vaccines-blood-biologics/questions-about-vaccines/bovine-derived-materials-used-vaccine-manufacturing-questions-and-answers) pre-dates the mRNA vaccines, so it isn't much use in an answer, but it addresses the side issue raised of BSE risk of from cattle-derived ingredients.

Comment: Does "vegan" mean "does not contain stuff from animal origin" or "no stuff from animal origin was used for production" to you?

Comment: “which it normally has to do as well?” — does it?! Source for that statement? — Furthermore, is there *any* approved medication that hasn't undergone animal safety testing? I thought that was usually part of regular approval (prior even to phase 1). I know that precursors of mRNA vaccines were tested in animals (contrary to false claims by vaccine denialists).

Comment: @LangLаngС The point of my comment is that I’ve never heard this requirement and I see no reason to assume it to be true. So: what makes you think otherwise? — Yes, for *new* medication I would assume that *at some point* in its development animal (safety) testing will have been performed. Animal models are simply indispensable to much of modern biology. If this is incompatible with veganism then that’s very bad news for vegans (though obviously it shouldn’t be *news* to practitioners).

Comment: I don't think there is a universally agreed upon definition of vegan, which may make this question hard to answer objectively.

Comment: Here is my related question: https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/2312/617

Comment: Very minor side-note regarding the milk statement: casein derived from milk is used very often in the printing industry (paper sizing, binders and ink). This *may* be one reason they specifically mention it as used for manufacturing.

Comment: Note that the Novavax vaccine is _not_ vegan, as it uses moth cells for protein fabrication. Many other "old school" non-mRNA vaccines use similar techniques (the flu vaccine famously uses chicken eggs).

Comment: Are there really vegans who object to using wool?

Comment: @DJClayworth ["Why Is Wool Not Vegan-Friendly?"](https://www.veganfriendly.org.uk/is-it-vegan/wool/). The strictest interpretation is indeed quite complicated to live by…

Comment: @DJClayworth Also see https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/361/1250

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. The title asks whether they are vegan, but the actual question is if they are non-vegan. Which is the true question?

Comment: @LangLаngС you should read the German version of the press release of the scientists from Magdeburg university again. "Hauptmengen des industriell benötigten Cholesterols aus tierischen Quellen" means the largest part of industrially needed/used cholesterol is derived from animals. This does not mean that any vaccine worldwide ever used animal derived cholesterol. It does not even mean it ever gets used in any medicine at all. Maybe the largest industrial use of cholesterol is in sewage treatment plants and those rely on animal derived cholesterol.

Comment: Next sentence, the Magdeburg researchers warn that using animal derived cholesterol in medical products is potentially dangerous. Maybe this is just a warning so that no company would ever start using animal derived cholesterol in medical products. It is NOT a claim that any medical products currently do or ever have used animal derived cholesterol. However they do imply that the company CordenPharma has previously not been able to supply plant based cholesterol, but they do not talk about other companies which may have such a product for a long time already.

Comment: There is already a wealth of misinformation about vaccines in general and COVID-19 vaccines in particular, and the vegan monkey wrench is probably in the machinery to stay. Every answer is wrong in some sense, and every answer is right in some sense. Arguing about the details of every answer is not helpful. What would be helpful is a statement by the OP that no answer will ever be accepted so people can move on.

Comment: @LangLangC I hope the OP does accept an answer. After looking at all the extended technical discussion of sources that may or may not be right, I had little hope. It's hard to say tactfully that the entire exercise seems to have become a waste of time. Pardon my cynicism.

Comment: [This document](https://www.edqm.eu/sites/default/files/medias/fichiers/European_Pharmacopoeia/The_European_Pharmacopoeia/European_Pharmacopoeia_10th_Edition/Comments/comments-concerning-revised-texts-pheur-106.pdf) suggests that the European Pharmacopoeia Commission decided in November 2020 to amend 2397 so as to allow parenteral use of synthetic cholesterol.

Comment: One must also acknowledge the possibility that Pfizer is using differently-sourced cholesterol in batches of vaccine intended for delivery to the UK and for delivery to the EU.  [This webpage](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.vrg.org/blog/2021/02/01/pfizer-biontech-covid-19-vaccine-ingredients/) raises the same possibility in a UK/US context.

Comment: @DanielHatton WOW! Great find! May I ask how you found that document? I did specifically search the European Pharmacopoeia website for "cholesterol" and still missed it somehow. Also, may I edit my answer to include that? Thanks!

Comment: @BarryHarrison On the plain Google search `european pharmacopoeia synthetic cholesterol`, that document was the fifth hit.  It doesn't quite clear everything up, because LangLangC subsequently found a source (also on the EDQM site) indicating that the revisions approved in November 2020 don't come into force until January 2022.  But yes, by all means edit the information into your answer.

Comment: WHy on earth would it matter if it was vegan, *sigh* I sometimes get so overwhelmed with the idiocy of large groups of people. If people avoid taking the vaccine because it somehow contains an infinitesimal piece of animal - and proceed to nurture a devastating pandemic, they have officially lost every moral fiber in their core.

Comment: @StianYttervik What matters is truthful info given out: I do not judge people for deciding to eat kosher, halal, or vegan… (while having my opinions on each ;). What I do mind is telling people who demand truthful info on sth that's important for them just something out of convenience that is not truthful. Whether 'should one take the shot or not' I leave to all individuals to decide for themselves.

Comment: @LangLаngС Right you are. I sometimes let frustration run amok. I still hold the opinion that the implication of evaluating not taking a vaccine for covid-19 based on its vegan-ness (or kosherness, whatever) is basically evil incarnate. I can understand those who don't trust governments, or corporations, that is a reasonable (though perhaps not rational) reason. But *this* ? oh well.

Comment: @StianYttervik As far as "moral fibre" goes, imagine for a moment that you value the life of a chick embryo equally with the life of a human: I'm not sure that's a position I share, but it's by no means a ridiculous position.  Well, the number of fertilised hen's eggs used annually in manufacture of influenza vaccines is of the same order as the total human population of the Earth...  Thankfully, the developers of (at least) the Pfizer, AstraZeneca, and Moderna CoViD-19 vaccines have (subject to a final answer to this question) made sure that no analogous argument can be deployed against them.

Comment: @DanielHatton exactly. If you equate the life of a chick embryo to the life of a human you are by most moral definitions, pitch black evil. Even a utilitarian would flinch at such a statement. Hell is filled to the brim (figuratively) of people with much less nefarious ideas and the volition to carry out plans to that end.... But I admit to pulling this particular comment chain way off course.. If you feel obliged to answer, let's move it to a chat.

Comment: @LangLаngС In any country where health care is (at least partially) communally funded (e.g. from taxation) the problem I have is not that "people can make idiotic personal decisions for bogus reasons" but that "when they do so, I and everyone else has to pick up part of the cost of their idiocy". if people choose to die in the gutter for personal reasons, that's fine by me. If the choose to refuse recommended treatment and I end up paying part of the cost of the consequences, that is NOT OK by me!!!

Comment: @StianYttervik It matters to me, even though I do take vaccines that contain animal products, because I would like it if they do not contain animal products in the future. A major vaccine that doesn't contain animal products represents a step in the right direction. (Also note, vegans do not generally equate the life of a chicken embryo to a human. In fact, unfertilized eggs are not even embryos. Rather vegans are concerned for hens that lays eggs, and male chicks of egg laying breeds who are killed shortly after hatching).

Comment: @Vaelus Sorry, it wasn't my intention to imply that most (or indeed any) vegans value the life of a chick embryo and that of a human equally.  (I myself am a mere lacto-ovo-vegetarian, not a vegan, so I'm not qualified to imply any such thing.)  Note that the example I gave concerned the use of _fertilised_ eggs in the production of influenza vaccines.  Stian suggested taking this to chat, and if anyone thinks there's mileage in continuing, there's a room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126831/discussion-on-question-by-langlangc-are-the-mrna-vaccines-from-pfizer-and-modern).

Comment: Thanks @DanielHatton! I didn't do a plain Google search and searched the site itself. I now know better. May I ask what source LangLangC found? Thanks again!

Comment: @BarryHarrison It's [this document](https://extranet.edqm.eu/4DLink1/4DCGI/Web_View/mono/2397), linked towards the end of LangLangC's answer.

Comment: @DanielHatton Thanks! I see it now. The "implementation date" for 10.6 is 1 January 2022.

Comment: It seems "vegan" is taken as either "yes" or "no". But there would be a huge difference between having to kill hundred chickens for each vaccine dose, and one single chicken having to provide a tiny amount of some ingredient; enough for the whole population.

Comment: @gnasher729 While it is true that less harm is better than more harm, many vegans consider efforts to reduce the scale or magnitude of harm to animals counterproductive without an explicit end goal of eliminating all unnecessary harm to animals. The idea is that, often, efforts to only reduce, but not eliminate harm are only tools for people to become more comfortable perpetuating harm indefinitely.

Answer (score 78):

> Does Pfizer/BioNTech's Comirnaty/Tozinameran mRNA vaccine contain anything derived from animals, specifically animal-derived cholesterol, making it non-vegan?

**No. Neither the cholesterol nor any other ingredient is animal-derived.**

The UK Department of Health and Social Care published a "Public Assessment Report" [last updated on June 4, 2021](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/regulatory-approval-of-pfizer-biontech-vaccine-for-covid-19/summary-public-assessment-report-for-pfizerbiontech-covid-19-vaccine). In [this report](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/944544/COVID-19_mRNA_Vaccine_BNT162b2__UKPAR___PFIZER_BIONTECH__15Dec2020.pdf), they describe the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine's various ingredients, separating them into a section on the "active substance" (mRNA) and a section on the "excipients" (everything else in the vaccine). Excipients are "[a constituent of a medicine other than the active substance](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/human-regulatory/marketing-authorisation/product-information/reference-guidelines/excipients-labelling)," and include the lipids (and cholesterol) used in the vaccine. The report writes that

> No excipients of animal or human origin are used in the finished product.

This leaves the mRNA. According to the same report, the mRNA is not derived from animals either. To produce the mRNA, DNA is mass manufactured in *Escherichia coli*, a bacterium. The DNA is then converted (or, in biology parlance, transcribed) to RNA *in vitro* (i.e. not in an animal).

Thus, no ingredients in the Pfizer vaccine are derived from animals.

---

For those interested, the ingredients in the Pfizer vaccine [are](https://www.fda.gov/media/144414/download) "mRNA,
lipids ((4-hydroxybutyl)azanediyl)bis(hexane-6,1-diyl)bis(2-hexyldecanoate), 2
[(polyethylene glycol)-2000]-N,N-ditetradecylacetamide, 1,2-Distearoyl-sn-glycero-3-
phosphocholine, and cholesterol), potassium chloride, monobasic potassium
phosphate, sodium chloride, dibasic sodium phosphate dihydrate, and sucrose."

---

## The above is a complete answer.

It remains nearly identical to my initial answer. Additional info to specifically address LangLangC's concerns:

LangLangC believes that the UK government statement that the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine does not contain excipients of animal origin (quoted in my answer) contradicts with the European Pharmacopoeia and therefore contradicts with "the law." LangLangC believes that the vaccine must fully comply with the European Pharmacopoeia and, therefore, the cholesterol must be animal-derived. I don't believe there is a contradiction or that EU law requires fully complying with the European Pharmacopoeia.

The European Medicines Agency, which is responsible for regulating vaccines in the EU, has published an aptly-titled "[Assessment report](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/comirnaty-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf)" on the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine.

In this report, they devote a section to "Manufacture of the product and process controls." Here is the section on "Control of excipients."

> ALC-0315 and ALC-0159 are novel excipients, not previously used in an
> approved finished product within EU. Additional information is
> provided separately in Section A.3 of the dossier.
>
> DSPC is a non-compendial excipient sufficiently controlled by an
> in-house specification.
>
> Cholesterol is sufficiently controlled according to the Ph. Eur.
> monograph with additional tests for residual solvents and microbial
> contamination.
>
> The other excipients (sucrose, sodium chloride, potassium chloride,
> disodium phosphate dihydrate, potassium dihydrogen phosphate and water
> for injection) are controlled according to respective Ph. Eur.
> monograph.
>
> The processing aids ethanol and citrate buffer are controlled
> according to Ph. Eur. standards and for HEPES and EDTA, reference is
> made to the active substance.

I find it very telling that *every single* excipient that is listed in the European Pharmacopoeia is described as "controlled according" to the pharmacopoeia ***except*** for cholesterol, which is "sufficiently controlled according" to the pharmacopoeia. This different phrasing for cholesterol allows for the cholesterol to *not* be animal-derived, in agreement with the UK government report.

---

I will now address other sources in LangLangC's question and LangLangC's answer:

Sources from LangLangC's question.

- [Article](https://www.pcrm.org/news/good-science-digest/covid-19-vaccines-safety-and-efficacy) from the [Physicians Committee for Responsible Medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physicians_Committee_for_Responsible_Medicine)

  > The Pfizer, Moderna, and Janssen vaccines are free of animal-derived ingredients, in contrast to many other vaccines that include shark squalene, gelatin, cholesterol, egg, and milk. Pfizer has reported that its vaccine used a cow’s milk component in the manufacturing process, but the vaccine does not contain this ingredient.

  I could not corroborate this statement with any other source. Searches of "cow" and "cow's milk" with "Pfizer" returned no relevant results. The linked source is a "dead link" and has not been archived. @[Jack Aidley](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/11782/jack-aidley) discusses this in [an answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/51920/48266) that I find insightful:

  > "We have no information allowing us to be certain as to how, or why, cow's milk is being used by Pfizer but given what we do know I would suggest it is quite plausible that it is being used in quality control testing, although casein is also sometimes used in bacterial growth media I would be surprised if that was the case for E. coli."
  >
  > -- Read Jack Aidley's full answer [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/51920/48266)
- Two German news sources on synthetic cholesterol [mdr.de](https://www.mdr.de/wissen/uni-magdeburg-mrna-impfstoff-pflanzlich-statt-tierisch-100.html) and [University Magdeburg](https://www.ovgu.de/lipide-path-2,13,31924,31926.html)

  > At the moment, most of the cholesterol required by industry comes from animal sources: either by extraction from fat from sheep's wool or from animal tissue. Through human and veterinary medical devices there is a risk of transmission of spongiform encephalopathy (TSE), an irreversible damage to the brain. -- University Magdeburg, translated from German

  As [@laolux](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/59222/laolux) [pointed out](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/51916/are-the-mrna-vaccines-from-pfizer-and-moderna-vegan/51917#comment242572_51917), this says *most* and not all of the cholesterol required by *industry* and not medicine specifically. Additionally, Sigma-Aldrich [sells](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sigma/s5442) "synthetic cholesterol, animal component-free" so I completely doubt the University Magdeburg's press release that they are developing synthetic cholesterol for the very first time.
- [Quote](http://en.avt-avt.com/p-company.html) from AVT (Shanghai) Pharmaceutical Technology Co., Ltd

  > The medicinal cholesterol CHO-HP is in great demand every year. However, because it is a multi-chiral substance and is difficult to synthesize, it is currently obtained by two methods: animal tissue extraction and lanolin extraction. […] However, with the emphasis on drug safety, cholesterol derived from lanolin will surely gradually replace cholesterol derived from animal organs.

  This is irrelevant to the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine specifically.
- European Pharmacopoeia

  Reading monographs [0593, 0993, and 2397](https://crs.edqm.eu/db/4DCGI/web_catalog_CRS.pdf), which are relevant for cholesterol (and which I cannot access), might give me new insight. I currently have no comments here.
- Ingredients list of Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine

  I agree the vaccine contains cholesterol.

Sources from LangLangC's answer.

- EMA [Assessment report](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/covid-19-vaccine-moderna-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf) on Moderna vaccine

  No comment.
- > Control of excipients (P.4)
  >
  > 10. It should be confirmed that cholesterol will be controlled in line with Ph. Eur. monograph Cholesterol for parenteral use (2397) for future batches and not Ph. Eur. monograph Cholesterol (0993).

  I cannot access this source. Regardless, "it should be confirmed" does not mean it has been confirmed.
- The manufacturer Evonik partnering with Pfizer/BioNTech

  > Commercial lipid quantities are to be produced at Evonik's Hanau and Dossenheim sites in Germany as early as the second half of 2021 as part of a strategic partnership with BioNTech.
  >
  > […]
  >
  > Evonik already supplies one of the most important lipids for mRNA vaccines in pharmaceutical quality to multiple customers: A non-animal derived cholesterol under the brand name PhytoChol®.

  LangLangC seems to use this as a source for the fact that Pfizer/BioNTech isn't currently using manufactured cholesterol. I will cite [an article](https://www.vox.com/22311268/covid-vaccine-shortage-moderna-pfizer-lipid-nanoparticles) from Vox.

  > “Relatively small amounts of mRNA are enough to immunize a lot of people,” explained Pieter Cullis, a biochemistry professor who has been described as the “grandfather” of the lipid nanoparticle technology, and is the co-founder of the company Acuitas Therapeutics, whose tech has been licensed for the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine. “The holdup seems to be more on the manufacturing of the other components like the ionizable cationic liquid and cholesterol, which are two of the larger components of the lipid nanoparticle.”

  The quote talks about a partnership between Acuitas Therapeutics, a different manufacturing company, and Pfizer. The article also talks about *manufacturing* cholesterol for the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine.
- Merck sources

  > To meet the high demand for lipids, a key component of mRNA-based vaccines and therapeutics, Merck, a leading science and technology company, has launched a new, high-purity synthetic cholesterol product, nine months ahead of schedule. [Merck press release](https://www.merckgroup.com/en/news/accelerated-scale-up-of-lipids-26-05-2021.html)

  Earlier on in the article, the press release includes "One of a few companies that produces lipids in quantities needed to meet demand for mRNA therapeutics, including Pfizer-BioNTech Covid-19 Vaccine." This does not say Merck is the only company producing lipids (such as cholesterol) for the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine. It's entirely possible (even probable) other partners are involved.
- EMA [Assessment report](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/comirnaty-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf) on Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine

  The same report writes that "Cholesterol is sufficiently controlled according to the Ph. Eur. monograph" instead of just "Cholesterol is controlled," which was done for all other excipients included in the monograph. I find that difference telling as it allows wiggle room for the Pfizer/BioNTech vaccine to have used cholesterol that is not animal-derived, as the UK government report states.

  @[Daniel Hatton](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/59756/daniel-hatton) [found](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/51916/are-the-mrna-vaccines-from-pfizer-and-moderna-vegan/51917#comment242621_51916) a [document](https://www.edqm.eu/sites/default/files/medias/fichiers/European_Pharmacopoeia/The_European_Pharmacopoeia/European_Pharmacopoeia_10th_Edition/Comments/comments-concerning-revised-texts-pheur-106.pdf) dated June 2021 that says:

  > Cholesterol for parenteral use (2397)
  >
  > Definition: revised to allow the use of synthetic cholesterol; Test section indicates which tests
  > apply depending on the source of the cholesterol used (derived from wool fat or synthetic).

  @LangLangC found [another document](https://extranet.edqm.eu/4DLink1/4DCGI/Web_View/mono/2397) that says the "implementation date" of the above edition supplement is January 1, 2022.
- [German law source](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AMG/55.html)

  I don't know how strictly this particular law is enforced. LangLangC also writes "How this apparent 'deficiency' that the EMA asked Moderna specifically to rectify — but both manufacturers seem to ignore by the second half of 2021 — might be compatible with for example the German law AMG $55,8: remains to be seen (and is probably out of scope here)."

All this said, I will be sending a few emails to better understand what exactly is going on with the incomplete compliance with the Ph. Eur.

Comment: This takes one statement and declares it 'truth'. Thus you emphasize one side of the two possibilities. However: the Magdeburg researcher as well as the requirements by EurPh are in contradiction to this statement (and the ultimate source of cholesterol in Comirnaty still not cleared up. Is it half- or fully synthesized then? Plant-sterol or de novo sourced? How do you resolve that contradiction? How do you weigh that (unreferenced) assertion in the report you cite against another expert and 'the law'?

Comment: @LangLangC I don't see a contradiction. The Magdeburg researcher says cholesterol used in vaccines *commonly* comes from animal sources.  Pfizer says the cholesterol they use does not.

Comment: "No excipients of animal or human origin are used in the finished product" could easily mean that they were used in the production process, but are not present in the finished product, anymore. Regarding the property "vegan" that is quite relevant!

Comment: @I'mwithMonica - It COULD, if that phrase was all we had to go on, but then the answer goes through and details the processes, which shows that it does not.

Comment: @LangLаngС - The answers specifies, from the source, and also citing third party analysis.  That's a lot more detailed and specific than the general statement you say contradicts it.

Comment: @LangLаngС - No, that's not accurate. The analysis RECOMMENDED (the tables that contain these items are specifically labelled as such) that they be told that. They also requested an exemption specifically for this. Is there anything that suggests, given the need, exigency, as well as the safety and efficacy results in trials, that they were not granted that exemption? Keep in mind, that assessment report was published three months AFTER they got approved. It seems pretty clear that they were allowed to go, without that alteration, so, no animal products in that one.

Comment: @LangLаngС - Yes, and no. I don't think it's contrary to what the EMA said about Pfizer...... but those are, clearly (FDA, CDC, etc. references) written from a USA-centric standpoint, and that cholesterol product has been approved by the FDA. There should be a lot more detail about where that might be accurate, at the very least. I don't think Moderna misread it. I think they made a calculation that the synthetic would eventually be approved, they prefer to use it, and given the dire need for vaccine, they could get an exemption. I do wish more of the info was easily available, for sure.

Comment: @LangLаngС I haven't had time to read all the comments yet. Can you explain why EurPh is "the law"?

Comment: @lambshaanxy The press release of Magdeburg University states thet cholesterol used in industry is commonly animal derived. It never says that cholesterol in vaccines is commonly animal derived.

Comment: aaaaa says reinstate Monica, thanks for your suggested edit! I rejected it because I am not an expert in determining whether something is vegan or not. I can only say there aren't any animal-derived products in the vaccine.

Comment: @LangLаngС I will edit the answer to resolve what you see as a contradiction.

Comment: @LangLаngС Over an hour later, I've made the edits

Comment: devil's advocate: bacteria could be considered animals by more extreme vegans (yes, yes, extreme members of an already extreme group, I know).

Comment: @jwenting well. In that case suicide is the only option to avoid killing lots of bacteria via your immune system, eating, breathing, etc. But that would also kill a lot of bacteria in your guts etc. So no, that viewpoint is not "considerable".

Comment: @DonQuiKong whoever said such people are thinking in any way logically, or at all?

Comment: I spoke with a Pfizer representative on the phone on Jun 22, and they confirmed cow's milk was used in the manufacture of the vaccine. They provided me a corroborating document titled "ARE ANIMAL OR HUMAN CELL LINES USED IN THE MANUFACTURING PROCESS OF THE PFIZER-BIONTECH COVID-19 VACCINE?". However, in the version of the document currently accessible from Pfizer's consumer medical information website, the claim is absent. https://www.pfizermedicalinformation.com/en-us/document/a0r5I000001MzSpQAK/patient

Comment: I've uploaded the version of the document I received, which claims cow's milk is used in the manufacturing process, to the internet archive. It also specifically claims all other ingredients, including specifically cholesterol, are not animal derived. The representative also told me that milk was not used in the final vaccine, but early in the manufacturing process. https://archive.org/details/cons-does-the-vaccine-contain-animal-derived-materials-v-1

Comment: @Vaelus Thank you so much for finding that and sharing your find! That does clear up the question on cow's milk, and it's also helpful to know that according to the Pfizer doc, "All lipid components used in the vaccine are from plant-derived sources or synthetic derivatives and do not contain animal derivatives." Would you know if they *still* use cow's milk in the manufacture of the vaccine?

Comment: @BarryHarrison I do not know whether cow's milk is still used. I haven't called since.

Comment: @Vaelus Ok, thanks for your reply. I'll edit your new information into the answer if that's ok with you.

Comment: @BarryHarrison Of course

Comment: A bit late but just to add on the "it should be confirmed that the cholesterol..." in the EMA report part (I'm an industrial pharmacist). This means that the EMA assessment showed that Moderna was running QC on the cholesterol they received from their supplier according to monograph 0993, which is technically incorrect (because that cholesterol is for parentheral use, so a separate monograph), so EMA requested that they start QCing their cholesterol according to monograph 2397 and submit documented evidence that their QC procedures were changed for future batches

Answer (score 12):

**The attribution in the question is incorrect**. This quote from the article:

> Vaccines based on mRNA […] are still based on animal cholesterol, which has several disadvantages.

> For the industrial production of vaccines, the cholesterol is extracted from sheep's wool or animal tissue, for example. Here, however, there is a risk of triggering brain diseases through unintentional transmission - damage to the brain known as prion disease. A very well-known form in cattle since the 1990s is BSE.

is *not* attributed to Professor Dieter Schinzer of the University Magdeburg, nor to anyone else from the university. Tellingly, it switches to quotation for only this part, and for the main blockquote:

> Dadurch "… können solche Verunreinigungen und Kontaminationen nicht auftreten", sagt Dieter Schinzer, Professor am Institut für Chemie der Universität Magdeburg.

that is:

> As a result, "... such impurities and contamination cannot occur," says Dieter Schinzer, professor at the Institute for Chemistry at Magdeburg University.

There is no direction quotation, nor source, that supports the assertion regarding BSE. In fact, I am unable to find any evidence of any transmission of BSE (TSE, more precisely) to humans from extracted Cholesterol. In fact, rather than being claims made by Magdeburg university, these seem to be claims made by an unnamed writer for mdr.de.

Meanwhile, non-animal origin is [freely available for purchase](https://www.glentham.com/en/products/product/GE7110/) by any laboratory. Given this, there seems no reason to cast doubt on Pfizer's claims regarding the ingredients of their product.

---

Regarding a side point, rather than being curious, **the use of cow's milk is common in molecular biology laboratories**, typically in the form of dried milk powder or [casein-powder](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/DE/de/product/sigma/c7594). This is used as a blocking agent in many procedures, but particularly in northern blotting (used to detect RNA) and Southern blotting (used to detect proteins). We have no information allowing us to be certain as to how, or why, cow's milk is being used by Pfizer but given what we do know I would suggest it is quite plausible that it is being used in quality control testing, although casein is also sometimes used in bacterial growth media I would be surprised if that was the case for *E. coli*.

Comment: "BSE" is not the main point here, but the Magdeburg PR states: "Currently, the main quantities of industrially required cholesterol come from animal sources: either by extraction from fat from sheep's wool or from animal tissue. Via human and veterinary medical products, this poses a risk of transmitting spongiform encephalopathy (TSE), an irreversible damage to the brain. "Such impurities and contaminations cannot occur in the production of cholesterol from plant-based raw materials," says Schinzer." Main point *is:* how are non-animal/PhEur assertions compatible. What's in, how approved?

Comment: Whether there is any risk for TSE or not, in whatever, if animal-derived (I don't claim "Magdeburg is right", just "they claim it in connection with this"): https://ispe.org/pharmaceutical-engineering/march-april-2018/managing-potential-virus-and-tse-contamination  https://doi.org/10.1002/ejlt.201400219  Even EMA attests for Moderna (link in my A): "All materials conform with Certificates of Analysis (CoAs) or Certificates of Compliance, which includes verification of bovine spongiform encephalopathy/transmissible spongiform encephalopathy (BSE/TSE) certificates, as required."

Comment: The claim about TSE is relevant to the credibility of the source (mbr not Magdeburg Universität). The claim that *most* Cholesterol is animal sourced is completely irrelevant to whether the cholesterol in this vaccine is.

Comment: Most cholesterol in industrial use is not the same as most cholesterol in medical use. Medical use of cholesterol could be very tiny compared to other industrial use.

Comment: @laolux Please read again that parenteral use cholesterol *per default has to be* animal sourced, and not least because of cost/price in the past definitively was. Note that "industry" is used in context as *pharmaceutical* industry! And clearly, in that case for injection use—is there in fragrances, intermediates or cosmetics, lab reagents any potential for TSE? You try to take down a corollary hint-src with inadequate interpretation of that src. The credibility of MDR or OvGM still stands as immaculate after this.

Comment: @LangLаngС I am only commenting on the wording of the press release of Magdeburg University. There I do not see any comment that cholesterol has to be animal sourced by default. I am aware that many people are inclined to think that in this press release "industry" means "pharmaceutical industry". This may be intentional. The reason for the press release is to make the research work of Magdeburg University look impressive. At the same time they do not want to openly lie. So maybe their decision to only write industry is because pharmaceutical industry would be wrong.

Comment: @laolux Crucial word: "dadurch": "Currently, the main quantities of industrially required cholesterol come from animal sources: either by extraction from fat from sheep's wool or from animal tissue. *As a result*, there is a risk of transmission of spongiform encephalopathy (TSE), an irreversible damage to the brain, via human and veterinary medical products." *Couple* that with Ph.Eur.2397 in its current incarnation and you should see that the very vast majority of medical cholesterol for injections *has* (soon: 'had', see my updated A) to be animal sourced (in EMA jurisdiction).

Comment: @LangLаngС yes, crucial word indeed. It serves as a warning. "Using regular industrial material in medical products is dangerous, because ...". Just like using "industrial grade" silicone in medical products such as silicone implants is dangerous, as a French company well knows. The press release still makes no claim that most medically used cholesterol is animal sourced. Your other sources might (I am not an expert on this), but the press release does not and actually chose careful wording to avoid such claim.

Answer (score 8):

> It is clear that a requirement for prior animal testing poses a problem for strict vegans, for any vaccine. (...)
> Does Pfizer/BionTech's Comirnaty/Tozinameran mRNA vaccine contain in the final product animal-derived cholesterol, making it non-vegan?

I think the premise of this question is somewhat incorrect.

Even if a product contains animal-derived ingredients or was animal-tested, vegans will not always have a problem with that (and in that sense, calling it non-vegan would not make much sense if vegans would still use it).

I will start with [the definition of veganism](https://www.vegansociety.com/go-vegan/definition-veganism) by The Vegan Society which is considered canon by many vegans:

> "Veganism is a philosophy and way of living which seeks to exclude—**as far as is possible and practicable**—all forms of exploitation of, and cruelty to, animals for food, clothing or any other purpose; and by extension, promotes the development and use of animal-free alternatives for the benefit of animals, humans and the environment. In dietary terms it denotes the practice of dispensing with all products derived wholly or partly from animals."

I've highlighted the relevant part in bold.

To the best of my knowledge, all of the popular vaccines the majority of people have access to were made with animal-derived ingredients and/or were animal tested. At the same time, the scientific evidence suggests that not vaccinating ourselves we will inflict great harm to ourselves and others, and indirectly contribute to the death toll and the increased demand for other animal-based or tested drugs for treating people with COVID-19 by spreading the pandemic further.

Thus, avoiding a shot with a vaccine containing animal-derived or tested products is *not* "practicable" or, in the case of some countries with mandatory COVID-19 vaccination, e.g. [some regions of Russia](https://meduza.io/en/news/2021/05/25/yakutia-becomes-first-russian-region-to-introduce-mandatory-vaccination-against-covid-19), even possible.

(By extension, this logic applies to other animal-derived and tested drugs.)

The Vegan Society provides a good summary why it's wrong to apply the "vegan"/"non-vegan" labeling to COVID-19 vaccines in the current situation:
https://www.vegansociety.com/news/news/vegan-society-response-covid-19-vaccine

> As there is currently a legal requirement that all vaccines are tested on animals, at this point in time it is impossible to have a vaccine that has been created without animal use.

And here is another link on whether a vegan person should avoid taking prescription drugs that taps into the same logic:

[The Vegan Society - Medications](https://www.vegansociety.com/resources/nutrition-and-health/medications)

(Full disclosure: I'm vegan, me and most of my vegan friends have either taken COVID-19 shots or are planning to do so in the near future. And while this is a very interesting question and discussion, I doubt most anti-vax vegans refuse to vaccinate for this reason alone.)

Comment: The 'premise' isn't just 'avoid or not'. The premise is: '*is it* this or that', as no clear *evidence* for either is available, despite multiple sources giving assertions, seemingly in contradiction, firmly claiming or strongly implying one thing *and* the other. All the while leaving for EMA jurisdiction the problem that *the end product in principle would be required*  to contain animal based substances, unless exception was argued for and granted. But the latter being nowhere to be read in publications to settle this so far. "Why it's wrong to…" is a philosophical/political prescription.

Comment: @LangLаngС That's certainly an interesting question. But if you are only interested in whether or not animal-derived ingredients are a sine qua non for a vaccine, you should avoid using the word "vegan" to avoid confusion. Veganism is inherently philosophical and political. If you buy instant beef noodles and throw away the sachet with beef broth, the noodles are not going to become vegan despite not having any animal ingredients in them.

Comment: Well, that would shift the goal posts? The interest is firmly not on 'should one do or don't, tell us what to do'. The interest is on accurate & honest info on the ingredients. With that info present anyone, incl vegans of various strains, strictness & adherence can make up their own minds.

Comment: Yes, historically, the Vegan Society in the UK has taken the position that it's OK to take vaccines that contain squalene oil, gelatine, (battery?) egg etc., because of the "as far as is possible and practical" qualification.  However, (subject to a final answer to this question) Pfizer, AstraZeneca, and Moderna have now shown that it _is_ possible and practical to make an animal-ingredient-free vaccine for a virus with spike proteins; that may change some vegans' calculus for some pre-existing vaccines going forward.

Answer (score 3):

Supply chain arrangements are not required to be made public, although the regulatory agencies do know about them (due to [GMP requirements](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/human-regulatory/research-development/compliance/good-manufacturing-practice/eudragmdp-database)).

Regarding Pfizer/BioNTech's claim of non-animal cholesterol, it seems plausible because they have [partnered](https://eminetra.com/evonik-has-partnered-with-biontech-to-produce-lipids-for-the-covid-19-vaccine/404685/) with [Evonik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evonik_Industries) to make the LNPs, and Evonik [also](https://healthcare.evonik.com/en/pharmaceuticals/mrna-and-gene-delivery/phytochol) has a process to make plant-derived cholesterol, which they sell under the brand name PhytoChol. [At least the amount of] cholesterol [is](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5439223/) intimately involved in the efficiency of LNP delivery (of mRNA therapeutics), so it makes some sense to source the "whole delivery package" from the same company.

Interestingly enough, Evonik [acquired](https://corporate.evonik.com/en/evonik-strengthens-strategic-partnership-with-biontech-on-covid-19-vaccine-152784.html) the PhytoChol tech by purchasing the American company Wilshire Technologies, at the beginning of 2020 (in January). The latter company [had](https://cen.acs.org/business/biobased-chemicals/Evonik-acquires-phytochemical-firm-Wilshire/98/i4) only about 10 employees at the time, so it looks like it was mainly an intellectual property purchase.

The Moderna vaccine [paperwork](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/spikevax-previously-covid-19-vaccine-moderna-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf) with EMA (Assessment Report of 11 March 2021) actually names Phytochol explicitly as a component and it seems it has even been included in the Ph. Eur 2397, since it appears as "non-compendial and compendial “Synthetic Cholesterol (Phytochol)”", but the latter document (2397) is not public. (I could find out that the Ph Eur. [has been](https://www.edqm.eu/en/news/pharmeuropa-322-just-released) revised in April-June 2020.) EMA reviwers said something somewhat confusing about this namely that "to use non-compendial cholesterol has to be sufficiently justified" but also that "this should be clarified post-approval." Which suggests that they probably let Moderna manufacture it as Moderna proposed, for now.

I'll also note (since the question starts with an NHS quote) that the UK is no longer subject to EMA's approvals, so it's entirely possible that the UK's regulator (MHRA) might not have complained in the same way (as EMA). Interestingly the MHRA [uses](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/regulatory-approval-of-covid-19-vaccine-moderna/summary-of-the-public-assessment-report-for-covid-19-vaccine-moderna) the exact same EMA base report for data, but they gave their own approval, which has wording like "cholesterol" and/but "No materials of human or animal origin were used in the manufacture of COVID 19 Vaccine Moderna." For whatever that's worth, the British Islamic Medical Association also [said](https://www.britishima.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Detailed-Position-Statement-on-the-Moderna-Vaccine.pdf) regarding the Moderna vaccine that "The lipid nanoparticle contains cholesterol from a plant source."

Interestingly enough, Avanti Polar Lipids [also](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/RO/en/product/avanti/700100p?context=product) makes plant-derived cholesterol and [according](https://www.vox.com/22311268/covid-vaccine-shortage-moderna-pfizer-lipid-nanoparticles) to Recode it's also a contractor for Pfizer in the US. (Avanti is based in Alabama and is also a subsidiary of the British Croda company.) CordernPharma also contracts with Moderna in the US according to the same (Recode) article; it [turns out](https://www.cordenpharma.com/CordenPharma_and_Moderna_Extend_Lipid_Supply_Agreement_for_Moderna_Vaccine_mRNA-1273_Against_Novel_Coronavirus_SARS-CoV-2) it is its Swiss subsidiary that does that... via a sub-subsidiary in Colorado. And they [happen](https://www.cordenpharma.com/facile-scalable-synthesis-of-plant-based-cholesterol-botanichol-in-gmp-grade/) to make plant-based cholesterol as well, at least recently. Another US contractor for Pfizer/Biontech is MilliporeSigma of Mass. (factory in Missouri though); and they [also](https://www.chemengonline.com/milliporesigma-launches-synthetic-cholesterol-production-to-meet-vaccine-demand/) announced plant-based cholesterol tech/production by acquiring a German company (AmpTec). The FDA submissions however are covered in even more confidentiality than those to EMA, so I don't expect to find out who exactly supplies cholesterol to Pfizer or Moderna in the US... But it sounds somewhat plausible that they'd use plant-based cholesterol to some extent over there as well.

As far as I can tell, Pfizer and Moderna (and AstraZeneca) themselves don't seem to promise in PR statements more than [the fact](https://www.voanews.com/a/covid-19-pandemic_halal-status-covid-19-vaccine-worries-muslims/6199773.html) that there are no pork-derived products in their vaccines. Which leaves them the option to use other animal-derived cholesterol, if need be. (An Indonesian Islamic body [actually](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/asia/indonesia-astrazeneca-covid-19-vaccine-haram-permissible-islam-267141) disagreed with AZ even on that due (allegedly) to use of pork-derived trypsin in AZ vaccine production... but AZ [contradicted](https://english.alarabiya.net/coronavirus/2021/03/21/Coronavirus-AstraZeneca-says-no-pork-in-vaccine-after-Indonesian-council-claims-dose-is-haram-) them on that issue.)

Aside, the [cost](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/RO/en/product/sigma/c1231) in lab quantities of Phytocol (or equivalents) is a bit ridiculous: 500 euros for one gram (down to 160 euros/g for larger orders), but a Pfizer dose only has 0.2mg of cholestarol... so that would be some 0.03 (or less) euros/dose in bulk prices.

Comment: "Revised" meaning 'effective when'? As at least seemingly established on this thread: not within 2021? My understanding slll: if vegan (no animal derived cholesterol in vial _&_ no explicit exception)), then illegal until start '22.

Answer (score 2):

Status: unresolved

Preliminary summary:

Neither Pfizer nor Moderna make that information publicly available. Inquiries were so far unsuccessful. Some authority sources claim that the finished product would not contain anything animal derived. Some authority sources continue to claim that the products do contain animal sourced cholesterol. Neither side provides definitive evidence for their versions.

But within the area where the European Medicines Agency (EMA) regulations apply, the products would strictly have to contain cholesterol sourced from sheep's wool fat according to the definition set forth in monograph 2397 of the European Pharmacopeia (Ph.Eur.).

Exceptions to that rule — that is about to change to also include synthetic sources starting in 2022 — are possible but have to be granted. That information on whether an exception was granted or not is also not publicly available.

Publicly available info suggests that from the second half of 2021 at least a large part of cholesterol produced for the products will come from synthetic sources.

Initially both companies were told by the EMA to adhere to monograph 2397 standards and use cholesterol from wool fat.

That leaves a lot of direct and circumstantial evidence to point towards the current *possibilities:*

1. Both companies currently adhere to monograph 2397, and indeed use animal sourced cholesterol in the finished product.
2. The companies may have gotten explicit approval to use non-compendial cholesterol, but this exception to the rules is not made public so far.
3. The companies did not get the explicit approval to deviate from the current Ph.Eur. standards,  but use plant-based or synthetic cholesterol anyway. This seems not impossible but rather unlikely,  as that would mean that the products would currently be not marketable at all.

The above applies to the area of mainly Europe under jurisdiction of the EMA. Inferences about other regions were the products are marketed as well are not possible and await further clarification, as again: neither Pfizer nor Moderna disclosed this information.

Personal evaluation:

---

Evidence gathered:

The European Medicine Agency (EMA) published two assessment reports, one for Moderna and Pfizer.

For Moderna, it indeed states it indeed contained a non-animal derived cholesterol at the time of the assessment and that it would be *therefore* in violation of the European standards as codified in the European Pharmacopeia (Ph.Eur.):

> Concerning the use of *non-Ph. Eur.* grade cholesterol also cited by the company applicant a request to only used Ph. Eur. cholesterol has been requested (REC)). […] (EMA/15689/2021 Page 22/169)
>
> c) Cholesterol is stated to be non-compendial and compendial “Synthetic Cholesterol (Phytochol)”, whereas compendial is not further defined. In the Ph. Eur two monographs are provided for cholesterol, monograph 0993 and monograph 2397.
>
> For parenteral use cholesterol **has to be in compliance to monograph 2397.** *[emphasis added, LLC]*
>
> The applicant is advised to solely use cholesterol of this quality and to update the provided specification and related documentation accordingly, to use non-compendial cholesterol has to be sufficiently justified.
>
> 3. P.4 Control of Excipients a)  The applicant should provide evidence that the impurities and/or degradation products resulting from PEG2000-DMG, cholesterol and DSPC have been sufficiently investigated and do not result in the formation of lipid-RNA species by 31-01-2021.
> 4. P.5 Control of finished product The applicant provide evidence to confirm that the impurities and/or degradation products resulting from PEG2000-DMG, cholesterol and DSPC have been sufficiently investigated and do not result in the formation of lipid-RNA species by 31-01-2021.
>
> — 11 March 2021 / EMA/15689/2021 Corr.1*1 / Committee for Medicinal Products for Human Use (CHMP) COVID-19 Vaccine Moderna
> Common name: COVID-19 mRNA Vaccine (nucleoside-modified) Procedure No. EMEA/H/C/005791/0000 Assessment report EMA/15689/2021 Page 162/169 ([PDF](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/covid-19-vaccine-moderna-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf))

A similar concern was issued for Pfizer as of 30. November 2020 for their application of approval:

> Control of excipients (P.4)
> 10. **It should be confirmed that cholesterol will be controlled in line with Ph. Eur. monograph Cholesterol for parenteral use (2397) for future batches and not Ph. Eur. monograph Cholesterol (0993).**
>
> Amsterdam, 30 November 2020
> EMA/CHMP/641856/2020EMA/CHMP/641856/2020
> Committee for Medicinal Products for Human Use (CHMP) ([link](http://82.221.129.208/covidvax.odt))

The substance "Phytocol® Puriss" was developed by [Wilshire Technologies in the USA](https://www.wilshiretechnologies.com/transferred/?id=9553) and is marketed through Evonik. Concluding from ads it seems to be [available at least since 2016](https://www.europeanpharmaceuticalreview.com/news/43718/parenteral-grade-vegetable-derived-cholesterol-fda-dmf-29599/). Price seems to be [50 g for $8,410.00.](https://sg.vwr.com/store/product/24579803/cholesterol-synthetic-phytochol-gmp)

The manufacturer Evonik is *now* also partnered with BionTech the developer of the Pfizer product:

> Commercial lipid quantities *are to be produced* at Evonik's Hanau and Dossenheim sites in Germany *as early as the second half of 2021* as part of a strategic partnership with BioNTech.
>
> […]
>
> Evonik already supplies one of the most important lipids for mRNA vaccines in pharmaceutical quality to multiple customers: A non-animal derived cholesterol under the brand name PhytoChol®.
>
> — By Dan Hutchins : ["Evonik partners with BioNTech to manufacture lipids for COVID-19 vaccine"](https://www.news-medical.net/news/20210302/Evonik-partners-with-BioNTech-to-manufacture-lipids-for-COVID-19-vaccine.aspx), News-Medical.Net, Mar 2 2021. *[Emphasis added, LLC]*

Similar data is derived from [newspaper reports about previous suppliers of lipids like cholesterol for Pfizer: Merck and Acuitas (Feb 2021)](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/corona-impfstoff-herstellung-verlangsamt-durch-fehlende-rohstoffe-17178171.html).

Interestingly, Merck seems to supply both: animal cholesterol ([variant 1: C₂₇H₄₆O 5g/EUR 68,40](https://www.merckmillipore.com/DE/de/product/Cholesterol-Highly-Purified-CAS-57-88-5-Calbiochem,EMD_BIO-228111); [variant 2, explicitly from wool fat: C₂₇H₄₆O 1kg/EUR 1.730,00](https://www.merckmillipore.com/DE/de/product/Cholesterol-from-wool-fat,MDA_CHEM-103672)) *and* [synthetic cholesterol SyntheChol®, C₂₇H₄₆O, price on request](https://www.merckmillipore.com/DE/de/product/CHOLESTEROL-PLANT-DERIVED-SyntheChol,MDA_CHEM-137132).

While the company indeed claims for all variants that they would meet Eur.Ph. standards for quality, they do not disclose *how* the synthetic variant would be able to comply to the most applicable regulation monograph 2397. The simple listing of "Ph.Eur." is therefore only in compliance with monograph 0993, and thus not for injectable use per se.

Merck did state very recently, that they are new to this, since February 2021, and *now* getting ready:

> To meet the high demand for lipids, a key component of mRNA-based vaccines and therapeutics, Merck, a leading science and technology company, has launched a new, high-purity synthetic cholesterol product, nine months ahead of schedule.
>
> —Merck: ["Merck Accelerates Scale Up of Lipids to Meet Covid-19 Demand"](https://www.merckgroup.com/en/news/accelerated-scale-up-of-lipids-26-05-2021.html), Press Release, Darmstadt, Germany, 26 May 2021

The other partner [Acuitas seems to be focussed on the Lipid-Nano-Particles other than cholesterol.](https://acuitastx.com/technology/lipid-nanoparticles/)

Initially, the Pfizer product was assessed by the EMA on conditional marketing approval as:

> **All excipients** except the functional lipids ALC-0315 and ALC-0159 and the structural lipid DSPC **comply with Ph. Eur.** The functional lipid excipients ALC-0315 and ALC-0159, are classified as novel excipients. Both structural lipids DSPC and cholesterol are used in several already approved finished products.
>
> — 19 February 2021
> EMA/707383/2020 Corr.1*1
> Committee for Medicinal Products for Human Use (CHMP)
> Assessment report
> Comirnaty
> Common name: COVID-19 mRNA vaccine (nucleoside-modified) Procedure No. EMEA/H/C/005735/0000 EMA/707383/2020 Page 23/140 ([PDF](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/comirnaty-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf)) *[emphasis added, LLC]*

While seemingly in conflict with the communication commentary upon application as of November 30 2020, (which lists 'what EMA thinks important), the EMA approval document confirms compliance with the compendium Ph.Eur., indicating the EMA thinks it complies with monongraph 2397, making the cholesterol animal sourced — per definitionem.

That means that the Moderna product might be vegan in the sense of at least 'does not contain animal derived cholesterol' in the finished product. Although this then is in violation of the current version of [European Pharmacopoeia (Ph. Eur.) 10th Edition](https://www.edqm.eu/en/european-pharmacopoeia-ph-eur-10th-edition).

How this apparent 'deficiency' that the EMA asked Moderna specifically to rectify — but both manufacturers seem to ignore by the second half of 2021 — might be compatible with for example the [German law AMG $55,8:](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AMG/55.html) remains to be seen (and is probably out of scope here):

> In the manufacture of medicinal products, only substances […] may be used […] which comply with the recognised pharmaceutical rules.

With "comply with the recognised pharmaceutical rules" [meaning](https://q-more.chemie.de/q-more-artikel/212/wirkstoffe-im-arzneimitteldossier.html) in accordance to the 'Good Manufacturing Practice' (GMP) as formulated in the German Pharmocopeia DAB (Deutsches Arzneibuch) and the European one, Eur.Ph.

Pfizer/BionTech brought a product to market that *did* and apparently does contain animal derived cholesterol, as assessed by the EMA. Meaning that it is/was in compliance with Ph. Eur. and uses animal derived cholesterol — but Pfizer plans to change that in the second half of 2021, switching to the plant-derived versions of the substance that is used by Moderna as well. If it contains animal derived cholesterol it is surely 'not vegan' at the moment.

Parenteral cholesterol as used by other vaccines would be Mosquirix or Shingrix. For Mosquirix the EMA found the following:

> The applicant adequately justified the use of cholesterol that is compliant to Ph. Eur monograph Cholesterol <993>, instead of the monograph Cholesterol for Parenteral Use <2397> and will develop an endotoxin test for cholesterol raw material testing.
>
> — 23 July 2015
> EMA/CHMP/439337/2015
> Committee for Medicinal Products for Human Use (CHMP)
> Assessment report
> MosquirixTM
> International non-proprietary name: Plasmodium falciparum and hepatitis B vaccine (recombinant, adjuvanted)
> Procedure No. EMEA/H/W/002300/0000 page 26/175 ([PDF](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/medicine-outside-eu/mosquirix-public-assessment-report_en.pdf))

Which means that the EMA found the reasons presented to them for not using sheep's wool as a source and thus violating 2397 satisfactory. As long as the alternative source in compliance with 0993 would be monitored closely for "endotoxins". Note the date of cost-effective alternative source availability for non-animal cholesterol and the need for monitoring endotoxins closely. This is apparently still exclusively animal sourced but just not from wool fat.

Such explicit assessment and a given OK are still absent from any publicly available material I could find. Pfizer and Moderna were asked to provide either compliant products or justify not doing so. It seems they have not done so, as at least EMA has not published documentation for the manufacturers doing that to EMA's satisfaction.

Unless further information comes forward on this, we have to regard the claims made by the UK NHS and the Vegetarian society, both relying on information from Pfizer as dubious: according to EMA assessment, Pfizer's product was conditionally approved for the EU market with, and currently does contain, animal derived cholesterol.

The exact ingredients used are not fully publicly disclosed by the manufacturer.

As of November 2020 (PDF) — and in parallel to the requests to the manufacturers to adhere to monograph 2397 — there was discussion *within* the EMA to amend Ph.Eur..

The newest supplement 10.6, agreed upon in November 2020, published in May 2021, and *to be implemented* in *2022*

> [image]

[Monograph 2397 will allow the use of either wool fat or synthetic cholesterol:](https://extranet.edqm.eu/4DLink1/4DCGI/Web_View/mono/2397)

> Status    In use
> Monograph Number    02397
> English Name    Cholesterol for parenteral use
> Pharmeuropa 32.2
> Published in English Supplement 10.6

As detailed in the history of revisions here:

> SUPPLEMENT 10.6
> Definition: revised to allow the use of synthetic cholesterol; Test section indicates which tests apply depending on the source of the cholesterol used (derived from wool fat or synthetic).
> Identification: section updated.
> Related substances: test introduced for synthetic cholesterol.
> Bacterial endotoxins: test deleted as covered by the general monograph Parenteral preparations (0520).

Which means that with the start of 2022, both manufacturers do no longer need to use strictly wool fat derived cholesterol, or present an accepted reason for using non-compendial cholesterol, as then synthetic cholesterol will be compendial as well.

An explanation for the demonstrated need to watch out for the given risk of transmissible spongiform encephalitis (TSE) in the University
of Magdeburg press release when employing animal derived cholesterol and the historic genesis of monograph 2397 *requiring* wool fat as the *only* compendial source *not in need* for exceptions when intended for parenteral use: these were meant as an explicit [security](https://ispe.org/pharmaceutical-engineering/march-april-2018/managing-potential-virus-and-tse-contamination) measure to avoid [any risk](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ejlt.201400219) of TSE, as detailed also in chapter "5.2.8. Minimising the risk of transmitting TSE via medicinal products" especially section "6-7. Wool Derivatives" in Ph.Eur. 10.0. (p670 printed version).

The quality, source and status of both products *now* remains to to be ascertained by official sources.

A Freedom of Information request for transparency on this matter to the EMA from January 2020 is blocked and delayed to this day. (Publicly visible in English and German language at
— [FragDenStaat: Antrag nach EU-Verordnungen 1049/2001 sowie 1367/2006: "Impfstoffe [#210033]" Datum: 28. Januar 2021 / Deadline: 18. Februar 2021](https://fragdenstaat.de/anfrage/impfstoffe/#nachricht-605044), last exchange listed as of June 15, 2021.)

Comment: Why are you complicating your already long answer with all this stuff about compliance, which is irrelevant to your original question?  Also, despite all the verbiage you've expended here, I'm still not seeing a "smoking gun" proving that Pfizer is using animal-derived (lanolin) cholesterol.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a massive simplification. The acronyms aren't made clear, the block quotes aren't provided with enough context, and the takeaways are buried in the text. It's extremely hard to understand.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Simple: because it _is_ complicated. EMA says Pfizer did comply. If it did comply, it contained animal derived cholesterol. Thus the simplistic NHS assertion must be quite false. Moderna didn't comply. Pfizer obviously either didn't as well (EMA simply trusting Pfizer, which didn't tell the truth to EMA, but to NHS?) or at least plans to go non-animal _now_. From 2nd half '21 both will not comply to either Ph.Eur. or AMG and go vegan—that is, unless they were vegan all along and thus Pfizer did never comply.  Or there comes an explanation, official, that clears this conundrum.

Comment: @jdf I added more spelling out of the most relevant acronyms earlier. Please re-check which you seem essential for comprehension yet still missing. // But: Do you realize the impossible goals you set forth? Demanding simplification + shorter, yet *more,* especially context? If I give you more context (which will also be available at the links I provided), will you then complain that the criterion shortness got even worse?

Comment: "do no longer need to use strictly wool fat derived cholesterol". It's not clear at all that they *need* to use wool-fat now. Moderna's 2021 submission to EMA already included Phytochol as a component.

Comment: @Fizz Well, currently, that's still a _hard_ requirement, manufacturers listed ('proposed'?) 'alternatives', and EMA complained about that (as quoted) so that the manufacturers get in line. Or did I misread that?

Comment: In somewhat broken English, EMA said (to Moderna) "to use non-compendial cholesterol has to be sufficiently justified." But it's not clear if they were unhappy with Phytochol or the justification for it.

Comment: Later on EMA also says "This should be clarified post-approval." Which suggests that they let Moderna manufacture it as [Moderna] proposed, for now.

Answer (score 1):

[Another source](https://www.sps.nhs.uk/articles/advising-individuals-with-religious-or-other-dietary-practices-and-beliefs-on-their-suitability-for-the-covid-19-vaccine-pfizer-biontech/), also within the UK NHS, says of the Pfizer-BioNTech vaccine

> All lipid excipients used in the vaccine are either from plant-derived sources or are synthetic and have no animal components.

which is a bit more specific than the source linked in the second line of the question.